# context.drawImage fails intermittently

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, canvas, drawimage

I have tried almost all suggestions on StackOverflow relating to this, including:

1. Loading the image directly from source
2. Waiting for the image to load before drawing it on the canvas
3. Verifying that the image has loaded using image.complete, before attempting to draw it on the canvas
4. Placing the code inside $(document).ready
5. Placing the code under $().ready
6. Delaying the drawImage function for a few seconds after loading the image
7. Throwing an alert, before drawImage
8. Making sure that the image is visible when drawImage is called
9. Using a base64 value instead of the image element
10. Using image.onload
11. Using addEventListener instead of image.onload

Even after all this, the context.drawImage fails intermittently, resulting in a blank canvas
Despite of all the efforts, I can't reproduce the failure. It's absolutely intermittent.

Is there a way to find out programmatically if the drawImage function has failed?
Also, is there a more dependable way to draw the image on the canvas?

Comment: What size of image / canvas? Does this happen in a single browser? Are you using filters/compositing? Can you show at least one of these attempts? Do you have anything else running on that page? Do you have active browser extensions? Could anything resize your canvas after you drew on it? For debugging, you can programmatically check if it failed by using `getImageData` if the pixels have changed. You could also try to generate an ImageBitmap from our <img>: `img = new Image(); img.onload = e => createImageBitmap(img).then( bmp => ctx.drawImage(bmp,0,0)).catch(console.error); img.src=url;`

Comment: Thanks Kaiido, that's what I needed. I created a failsafe function using getImageData and createImageBitmap and it now works like a charm. I've tested it a few times now and it did not fail even once. Kudos!!